# Only execute once previous command is triggered

Tags: jquery

How do I make sure that each of these commands are triggered once the previous command has been triggered and completed?

```
$('.thumb').unwrap('.wrapper')
$('.thumb').wrapAll("<div class=\"page\"></div>");
$('body').prepend('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
wrap_thumbs();
```

Answer (score 1):

These will already execute in order; Javascript in the browser is single-threaded, so every operation must complete before the next one will execute.

Comment: Also the first 2 lines can be shortened using jQuery's chaining: `$('.thumb').unwrap('.wrapper').wrapAll("<div class=\"page\"></div>");`